# REST API Input Validation Strategy

Tags: python, rest, api, validation, flask

I am implementing a REST API and need to validate the JSON API inputs for the CREATE and UPDATE endpoints.
The goal is to send a 400 error prior to doing any processing if the inputs are not valid.

In the past, like most people I have been using some sort of schema validation tool such as Marshmallow/Cerberus/Schema/Voluptuous/Schematics (I'm using Python here)

But my DB models themselves can (and should?) contain validators and/or constraints to guaranty the consistency of the data in my database.

With that in mind my general strategy for record creation looks like this:

```
create_record(inputs):
    errors = validate_schema(inputs)
    if errors:
        send_400(errors)

    try:
        record = create_record(inputs)
    catch:
        send_500()

    return record
```

So it sounds like I need to perform some kind of data validation in two places which has some potential downsides:

- Need to maintain code in two different places
- If my schema validation is ever more permissive than the DB validators/constraints, the validation will pass but the record creation will still fail and will result in a 500 instead of 400.

Is there some DRY strategy that is recommended for this?

Answer (score 3):

I would advise against `HTTP 400` for syntactically correct (here a `400` would be misleading), but semantically incorrect (aka *invalid*) request. But that should not be the topic here.

The question is more about *validation* and *DRY*.

I think, there is no golden rule to follow here. If you are doing a modern web application, there is a tradeoff between double book-keeping, *DRY* and maintainability.

The typical stack has:

- A frontend for the browser (which needs to implement some kind of validation)
- A backend (which needs to implement some kind of validation)

And in your case, you have validation in your code and in your DB.

For ease of use - from a user's perspective - it makes sense to have a validation layer on the client, ready to interactivly indicate errors and give advice how to improve the input. Gone are the days, where you filled out your `Form`, sent to the server and had to re-enter everything because there were errors.

That said, there is always - at least some kind of - double book-keeping between client and server. I saw people trying to write frameworks including abstract languages which kept the *business logic* in one place and used code generators to generate clientside and serverside code to prevent *DRY* at least from a logical point of view. Which ended in a hard to grasp and hell to maintain software.

Coming to the question about *DRY* in the backend. 
It would make sense to split your validation logic into two parts:

1) things a database could handle best:

- Constraints (»Is this thing *unique*?«, »Does this thing *refer* to something known?«)
- Datatypes (»Is this really a *date*?«)
- (maybe data access - if you implement users equaling DB users)

2) things your code does best:

- Validating postal codes
- Checking for completeness
  etc.

This leads to roughly two classes of errors emitting from your *data access layer*:

- technical errors (*the DB is gone*)
- semantical errors (*unique key constraint violation*)

The latter would be transformed into a `validation error`.

In case of `datatypes` you would end up with some kind of double checking - e.g. whether something is a date - which would be neglectable. And for the rest it is orthogonal / relatively DRY.

**BUT**: Depending on your *consistency requirements*
If you see your database as a kind of *last line of defense* you would implement more validation logic in the code as well as in the database (which would undermine *DRY*).

Answer (score 0):

The dry way would be do handle multiple types of errors from `create_record` rather than do validation for each different type of validation error there can be. For example

```
try:
  record = create_record(inputs)
catch InputsValidationError:
  send_400()
catch:
  send_500()
```